# How to change a specific datagridview column format

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview which displays my records in currency format. I set the DefaultCellStyle property permanently for the format **BUT** I have a particular column which I wanna display it values as an Integer.

The column i wanna change and what it displays:

```
    [AreaCode]
     15,00 €
     25,00 €
     60,00 €
```

My expectation:

```
[AreaCode]
   15
   25
   60
```

And here is my code which isn't working:

```
private void dgv1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
  var columnname = "AreaCode";
   if (e.ColumnIndex == dgv1.Columns[columnname].Index)
        {
            //Get the datagridview cell
   DataGridViewCell cell = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (cell != null)
            {
  this.dgv1.Columns["AreaCode"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D4";
            }

        }

    }
```

Thnx in advance

Comment: How about `D2` instead? `D4` makes your values as `0015`, `0025` and `0060`.

Comment: Hi
Sounds good but there is something wrong with my code. An Error:
Object reference not set to an object instance.

Comment: Read: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`this.dgv1.Columns["AreaCode"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";`

using `N0` this will format your areacode column to numeric with `0` decimal placess

```
private void dgv1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
      var columnname = "AreaCode";
     if (e.ColumnIndex == dgv1.Columns[columnname].Index)
        {
            //Get the datagridview cell
            DataGridViewCell cell = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (cell != null)
            {
             this.dgv1.Columns["AreaCode"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";
            }

        }

    }
```

**Note:** If you want some decimal places to then you can use `"N1"`,`"N2"` and so on....